# Assigning rights to sharepoint folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am new to powershell and a bit more experienced with Sharepoint.
I need to assign rights to a folder within a list to a specific user with Contribute.

Site is http://contoso.com/stores/Form1/001
List: Form1
Folder: 001
User: contoso\user001

I want the simplest code possible to assign a single user the "Contribute" right for the folder 001.

Thank you very much everyone!

When I google on the subject, every thread gets back to this site but I am unable to make this work. If someone could tweak it for me with my informations or make a new code for me it would be very appreciated. I will be glad to accept answer and boost your rep for it!
http://sharepoint2010tutor.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/grant-folder-permissionsharepoint-using.html

Comment: What is it that doesn't work in the example you linked to?

Comment: That's the problem, I do not know. At the end it just says "Completed" but I cannot see any errors or anything. And when I check, rights are not assigned.

Maybe it is me not placing the right values in the right places.
With the values I indicated in my initial post, if someone could place the right values in the right spots of the script, I could then test it on my environnement

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the user id of an existing SharePoint user when you call the `GrantUserPermission` function. Right now you're passing the permission level you want assign. That is already set in the role binding.

```
if($folder.Name.Equals("001"))
{
   # don't pass the permission level here --> GrantUserPermission("Contribute")
   # pass a valid SharePoint user.
   GrantUserPermission("adventureworks\jdoe")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is what I was using:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Add-SPShellAdmin
cls

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://contoso.com/stores")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()

function GrantUserpermission($userName)
{
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$spusers=    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection]$web.SiteUsers
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser=$spusers[$userName]
$sproleass=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipal]$spuser)
$folder.BreakRoleInheritance("true")
$sproleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"])
$folder.RoleAssignments.Add($sproleass);
Write-Host "Permission provided for user ", $userName
}
$doclib=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$web.Lists["Form1"]
$foldercoll=$doclib.Folders;
foreach($folder in $foldercoll)
{
Write-Host $folder.Name
if($folder.Name.Equals("001"))
{

GrantUserPermission("Contribute")
}

}
Write-Host "Completed...."
$web.Close()
$site.Dispose()
```